# Select multiple files individually and upload with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I am creating a multiple image uploader with JS & PHP where the user can select multiple files from one input. The upload script works great, the user can select multiple files at one time and upload them all without problem.

What I am trying to do is allow the user to select one file, then click the same input button and choose a 2nd file to upload. Right now, the user can do this and the images are both shown in the 'Preview' I have setup, but when clicking submit -- PHP only processes and uploads the most recently selected image and not the first as well.

Again, when you select multiple files at once the upload works fine, it just doesn't work when you select multiple files individually. Is there a work around for this?

Here is my file input & preview HTML:

```
<fieldset id="vehicle-image">
    <div class="form-group <?php if(isset($errors['image'])) echo "has-error"; ?>">
        <label class="section-title">Vehicle Image</label>
        <div id="ride-image-container" class="form-group">
             <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                 <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                        <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                        <input name="upl[]" id="ride_image" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
                    </span>
                    <div id="file_preview"></div>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($errors['image'])) { 
                            echo '<small class="help-block">' . $errors['image'] . '</small>';  
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And here is my PHP Processing the upload:

```
if ( $_FILES ) {
    $count;
    $files = $_FILES['upl'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
            );

            $_FILES = array("upl" => $file);

            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                $count++;
                $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$rid,$count);

                if(is_wp_error($newupload)) {
                    $errors['image'] = "Image upload failed!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Javascript to handle the image preview (may not be necessary, but I figured I would include it anyways -- This part works great):

```
<script>

    // Handle File Select
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }

            // Access the HTML5 FileReader API
            var reader = new FileReader();

            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                    '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('file_preview').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('ride_image').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

</script>
```

Is it even possible to do this type of functionality? If so, is there something wrong with my code that is preventing me from doing it?

Comment: you need to duplicate or link the image/file and upload it in the background, so you don't need to rely on the <input> to contain all the file data.

Comment: So the only way to do it is to AJAX upload the images before they click submit? What if I want to allow them to remove some selected images before uploading?

Comment: you don't have to upload them right away, and it shouldn't be too hard to come up with some UI to edit the listing before upload. you can add the the list onchange() to make sure that the files won't be lost if re-selected, and then send them all off with a FormData or even an actual invisible form if you swapout inputs.

Comment: I'm not worried about the UI to edit the listing, I just need to be able to upload multiple images individually rather than selecting them all at once. So you're saying ajax the image data to an array onchange then when the form is submitted process the uploads?

Comment: i would just make it so that the submit button uploads anything chosen, and the browse button adds anything selected to the list of stuff to be uploaded. much like gmail for example; you can add file attachments, add more files, and later remove some of them before sending the email. the only trick is that you need to grab the file data using URL.createObjectURL() or a FileReader() right away, because you can't read the file once another is chosen.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem some time ago, but I could figure out workaround and here is what I do. Everytime when user click and select files I add css class to file input and make it hidden, and then I append new file input with same properties  to the form. This works good and does not requires changes in backend, just slight changes on frontend. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work either. Now it only takes the first image selected, not the last.

Comment: I did not understand what take first image selected? You mean it upload oly first file selected or?

Comment: In my question I said PHP is only taking the last selected image and uploading it. When I made the change you suggested -- hiding the old input and appending a new one, it only takes the first image selected instead of the last.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I got this working by placing the hide/append code in the `handleFileSelect(evt)` function written above.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use File Reader object to read file data dynamically
Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Also you can use FormData object to create file objcet or any other form data dynamically
Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Solution: On selecting a file, you can read the file using file reader object and append to form data using the form data object. 
Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications